# Le "portrait chinois": Est-il courant ?

Tags: expressions, usage, france

Quand j'ai assisté aux cours de la langue française (FLE), je me souviens que l'on a bien travaillé avec ledit *[portrait chinois](https://www.portrait-chinois.com/)*. L'autre jour, je l'ai mentionné à mes étudiant.e.s (niveau bac+2) et ils/elles m'ont qu'ils/elles ne le connaissent pas. Je me demande si le "portrait chinois" est répandu en France, ou l'on l'utilise plutôt dans des classes du FLE.
Il en est de même pour le [questionnaire de Proust](https://www.portrait-chinois.com/questions-proust.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le *"Portrait chinois"* en tant que tel n'est pas tant répandu *(en dehors des personnes en art ou bien passionnées)*, en revanche en expliquant directement la définition de ce dernier, l'exercice devient plutôt clair

> Le portrait chinois est un jeu littéraire, dans lequel il s'agit de déceler certains aspects de la personnalité d'un individu ou d'identifier des goûts ou des préférences personnelles, au travers d'un questionnaire basé sur l'identification à des personnes, des objets ou des éléments divers. [Source](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portrait_chinois)

Peut-être qu'aborder le sujet en parlant du [**questionnaire de Proust**](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Questionnaire_de_Proust) les étudiants se rappelleront plus facilement.